# How to hide other panels or panes during coding

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

Using Eclipse Juno for Java & WindowBuilder

I have three panels of the same size that lay on top of each other - they have different widgets. During coding, they all display and clutter up what I'm doing.

I can show and hide them in runtime as needed but, I want to display only the one I'm working on *while* doing drag and drop of widgets.  I've tried using different panels and pane types (tabbed, layered...) and selecting opaque but, nothing hides them.

How do I hide the other (panes, panels...etc) during coding?

Comment: `I can show and hide them in runtime as needed but` - hope you use a `CardLayout` for this.

Comment: Also tried CardLayout but it didn't make a difference (maybe I missed something ?)

Comment: no, he meant that the proper way to show and hide them at runtime is cardlayout.  that won't actually help with what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  Among other reasons, my solution was to create separate classes per view.  So my frame would be its own class, it would maybe have a TabbedPanel (or whatever it's called), and then I would have a new class for each tab on that tabbed panel.  Each class would extend `JPanel` so I could plop it right in there.  That way not only is your gui design not cluttered up, but your code logic is separated into separate files, where it might belong anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't want to use separate classes. Want one class jframe with three panels or panes.  Yes, I can do it with different classes but that's not how I want to do this app...

Comment: you may be stuck then.  Silly GUI designer inadvertently promoting good coding practices :P

Comment: Hiding/showing 'layers' is standard for drawing programs, you'd think it would be a std feature in eclipse/wb...  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]** Answering my own question.
It may not be perfect or the best/correct way, but it works!

WindowBuilder wants to Surround other panels/widgets that are within it's bounds so, you have to trick it by using opaque, Order>forward/backward **then** setting the desired bounds (all panel sizes and bounds can be equal and will overlay nicely both during widget drag&drop and runtime).

Here's how to do it with a 3-Panel example (NOTE: WindowBuilder is buggy/in-consistent and often I needed to select the items *from the gui, not in the Components tree*).

1. Create your first panel. Add your widgets and border to it.
2. Create your second panel (the one you want to overlay on top of the first one). This second panel **MUST** not be completely inside the first panel - it **MUST** extend beyond the edges of the first panel (parts of it can be inside the first panel). This takes a bit of trial because of the 'surround', mentioned above.  Use the shift-key to stop the snapping.
3. Select the top panel in the gui, **NOT** from the Components tree, and toggle the Opaque property. The top panel (first or second) in the tree is the one you set to opaque and work on.
4. Add another panel and repeat the process.
5. Once you get your widgets/etc as you want them, use the property Bounds to set them all the same or as desired.  **After that, as long as you don't move a panel by dragging it, it will remain un-surrounded by the other panels.  If you move by dragging, it may get set to surround...**

I've done this a dozen times now and it works consistently.

**Below is a shot of 3 panels overlayed, un-surrounded and not opaque, thus showing widget clutter**

[image]

**Below is a shot after the bounds are set (and not surounded). Opaque and order not yet set:**

[image]

**Below is a shot with bounds set and panel 3 moved forward and opaque set:**

[image]

**Below is a shot with bounds set and panel 2 moved forward and opaque set:**

[image]

**... etc, etc...**  Now you can work on a panel that's ordered to the front and, naturally, use the setVisible in your code...